# message with redirection in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have application where I show list of all items from specified table. Then I have in this page link to create new record in database, where it redirect me to form page. After submit the form I want to redirect back to list of items with success message like f.e."Record was inserted". How to do it in laravel? I tried something like this , but this doesnt work:

```
Redirect::to("Homepage@list")->to('message', 'Record was inserted')
```

also I tried (but also it doesnt work):

```
Session::flash('message', 'Record was inserted')
```

and in blade:

```
Session::get('message')
```

Comment: you need to get you flash message in blade

Comment: how ? I tried: Session::get('message')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your code to

```
Redirect::to("Homepage@list")->with('message', 'Record was inserted');
```

and add the code for the flash message in your View

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success"><em> {!! session('message') !!}</em></div>
@endif
```

Comment: hmm are you getting any errors? or just doesn't display anything?

Comment: display nothing... but it works when in my controller instead redirect::to(..) i use :

Session::flash('message', 'Record was inserterd!');
return view('list');